# "Column may have been deleted by another using" error on populating list created through COM

Tags: error, com

I am creating a list using COM for Sharepoint 2010.

below is a snippet for the same:

```
        CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
        myCache.Add(new Uri("myURL"), "NTLM", myCred);



        // declare the ClientContext Object 
        SP.ClientContext _clientcontext = new SP.ClientContext(_context);
        SP.Web _site = _clientcontext.Web;
        // declare a ListCreationInfo 
        SP.ListCreationInformation _listcreationinfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();

        // set the Title and the Template of the List to be created 
        _listcreationinfo.Title = "NewListFromCOM";
        _listcreationinfo.TemplateType = (int)SP.ListTemplateType.GenericList;

        // Call the add method to the ListCreatedInfo 
        SP.List _list = _site.Lists.Add(_listcreationinfo);

        // Add Description field to the List 
        for(int i=1;i<4;i++)
        {
            someStr = "<Field Type='Number' DisplayName='Col0" + i + "'></Field>";
        SP.Field _Description = _list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(@someStr, true, SP.AddFieldOptions.AddToDefaultContentType);
        }


        // declare the List item Creation object for creating List Item 
        SP.ListItemCreationInformation _itemcreationinfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();

        // call the additem method of the list to insert a new List Item 
        SP.ListItem _item = _list.AddItem(_itemcreationinfo);

        _item["Title"] = "New Item from Client Object Model";

        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            someStr="Col0"+i+"";
            _item[someStr] = 100 + i;
        }


        // call the update method 
        _item.Update();
```

I wanted to create columns like = Col01, Col02, Col03.
Then create an item in the list, and update.

The list gets created successfully, but on updating I get an error:

```
        Column 'Col01' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.
```

Could someone pls help why this is happening?
The list exists, and I have tried deleting it and running the code again. It doesnt work.
I have tried using the static name (="_x0043_ol01") for Col01 but can't figure out how.

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I am looping through Column names, as actually I would be creating about 30 such columns of type=number and its tiring to do this manually. Thanks for your help!

Comment: call `_list.Update();` after the loop of adding fields

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri thanks for the comment. Now the error message has gone. But the new item I am inserting, that does not get entered into the list.

Comment: might be a stupid comment but do you have permissions to add list item, and also can you check if you get any error in ULS log

Comment: Haha, thanks for the idea, but I've checked - yes. I've manually created a list. I am able to programmatically add list items to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my list, the Static Name and Internal Name seem to be the same. I am not sure if this is the case normally. Using the Display Name was definitely failing.

Here is what worked for me:

1. adding _list.update();
2. Using static name as -

   ```
   _item["_x0043_ol03"] = comboBox1.SelectedText;
   ```

I just want to say thank you to the community, specially @ArsalanAdamKhatri and @TimeToShine . Thank you for all the time and energy you put into helping queries of us newbies! :)

Answer (score 0):

If what Arsalan suggested doesn't help then try loading column before trying to update them, as it has been done in this [article](http://geekswithblogs.net/mikebangoy/Default.aspx)

Also can you go to list through browser and check if columns are actually being created or not.

**EDIT**

> Try enabling the retention in the parent content type and re-publish
>   the associated content type.

[Similiar Problem](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/et-EE/sharepointadminprevious/thread/b188d6e6-245b-4887-9341-c4a074965ce8)

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer. The columns are being created, I checked in datasheet view. But the row isn't getting added? Going thru Mike's article. This was from where I understood the original code as well, but this did not work. Will try and update here in a minute!

Comment: I tried this again. With a new listname. Even after adding _list.update(), now I am still getting the same error message.

Again, list is being created from COM, but thenew item is not added.

Comment: I updated my answer :)

Comment: thanks for the update. but I am not able to figure out how to change the retentional policy? After going through the link.

also, now the regular updates are not working. manually created list also, i am not able to add list item. pls help! im completely stuck, although this was working before.

Answer (score 0):

call `_list.Update();` after the loop of adding fields

Use following code for adding List Item:

```
// call the additem method of the list to insert a new List Item 
SP.ListItem _item = _list.AddItem();

_item["Title"] = "New Item from Client Object Model";

for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        someStr="Col0"+i+"";
        _item[someStr] = 100 + i;
    }


// call the update method 
_item.Update();
```

No need for ItemCreationInformation

I hope this helps